# Кривое сравнение значений JSON хранилища, почему?

Tags: python, json, discord

```
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import os
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='7')
os.chdir(r'D:\Sublime Text 3\dis\test_systems\json_files')

@bot.command()
async def Test(message):
    with open('parametr.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, message.author)
    await add_Z(users, message.author, 10000)
    await X(users, message.author)
    await sendd(message)

    with open('parametr.json','w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

async def update_data(users, user):
    if not str(user.id) in users:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]['Z'] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]['X'] = 15000

async def add_Z(users, user, parametr):
    users[str(user.id)]['Z'] += parametr

async def X(users, user):
    users[str(user.id)]['X'] == 15000

async def sendd(message):
    await message.channel.send(f'Успешно!')

    with open('parametr.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    if 'Z' > 'X':
        await message.channel.send('да')
    else:
        await message.channel.send('Нет')
```

Сам код работает идеально, все значения в хранилище добавляет и всё делает как и должно.
Но сравнение выдаёт только одно значение, то что Z больше X, хотя в хранилище наоборот.

X всегда остаётся 15000, тут ошибок нет.

```
{"293396418834464768": {"Z": 10000, "X": 15000}}
```

Почему возникает ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

```
if 'Z' > 'X':
    await message.channel.send('да')
else:
    await message.channel.send('Нет')
```

Мне кажется тут у вас ошибка. Вы сравниваете константные строки. Тут всегда будет `True`, потому что как код символа `Z` конечно же больше кода символа `X`.

Наверное, вы тут хотели сравнить что-то другое, а не просто символы 'Z' и 'X'. Например:

```
if users[str(user.id)]['Z'] > users[str(user.id)]['X']:
```

Только надо достать ещё из `message` как-то `user.id`, а я в `discord` не силён, возможно это будет `message.author.id`:

```
if users[str(message.author.id)]['Z'] > users[str(message.author.id)]['X']:
```

Comment: в json хранилище значение Z равна 10000, а X - 15000, именно эти значения и хочу сравнить.

Comment: @Who тогда надо писать `users["Z"] > users["X"]`

Comment: @Danis там ещё `user.id` надо где-то взять

Comment: @Who Что-то типа как выше `users[str(user.id)]['Z']` надо вместо просто `'Z'`, но надо видимо из `message` ещё `user.id` добыть сначала

Comment: всем спасибо, всё понял, буду разбираться. @Danis